# Error: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Нужно посчитать количество символов b в массиве a, выдаёт ошибку **Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted**.
Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    char a[] = "";
    char b;

    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    int count = 0, cinso = 0;

    for (count = 0; a[count] != '\0';)
    {

        count++;

        if (a[count] == b)
        {
            cinso++;
        }
    }

    cout << cinso << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, выделяем место в памяти под строку `a`...

```
char a[] = "";
```

Выделен 1 (прописью: *один*) байт.

А сколько вы в нее читаете в

```
cin >> a;
```

Если больше 0 (прописью: *нуля*) символов, у вас проблемы. Потому что один байт надо оставить для нулевого символа...

Почему бы вам не указать размер массива для чтения побольше?

Comment: Действительно, исправил, благодарю!